# How to prevent certain namespaces from being logged using NLog in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nlog

I am using NLog in .NET 6 and it generates logs a file. I want NLog to skip certain logs. For instance there is a line like this in my file.

```
2023-08-17 14:00:44    
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ConsoleLifeTime.OnApplicationStarted
 1 ...blah blah
```

I want all `Microsoft.Extensions.*` namespaces not to be saved to this log file.

What modifications in the `NLog.config` file need to be made for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use **final** to avoid any problem with the order of the rules.

Add a rule (no matter where it is placed as long as it has final=true)

```
 <rules>

    <logger name="Microsoft.Extensions.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />


  </rules>
```

Furher information [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules).